# _lodash debounce not debouncing

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash, debouncing

Here is my code (angular 2):

```
<button (click)="click()">GO!</button>

debouncedFunc = _.debounce(()=>{
    console.log('bam')
  }, 1000, {"leading":true})

click(){
  this.debouncedFunc()
}
```

this fires off every event with no debouncing. I want to only hit my endpoint max once per second and ignore all others. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out 10 seconds after posting this. Funny how that works. All options needed to be declared:

```
 <button (click)="click()">GO!</button>

 debouncedFunc = _.debounce(()=>{
   console.log('bam')
 }, 1000, {"leading":true,"trailing":false})

 click(){
   this.debouncedFunc()
 }
```

Comment: note that calling the debounce function directly after the lodash declaration (this would let you skip that assignment step) does **not** seem to work. I wanted to cut out a step but it seems you have to assign it first.

Comment: You have to assign it first because debounce returns a function, and when you don't use returned function you create a new debounced function on every click